# How to declare a method?

Tags: typescript

I have a property decorator which generates some methods on a class. How do I get typing information about these?

```
class Foo {
  @GenerateGetterAndSetter() _bar: string;
  // How to do the following:
  declare public bar(): string;
  declare public bar(value: string): this:
}

let foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
```

The error I get is **TS1031: 'declare' modifier cannot appear on a class element**.

Comment: How is your decorator implemented? You can't have two methods with the same name in any case, are you aware of that?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Yes. My decorator works, it generates a single method which does different things depending on the `arguments.length`.

Comment: Ok, check my revised answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `declare` for non-ambient definitions.

You can however use the same trick that is used in mixins:

```
class Foo {
    @GenerateGetterAndSetter() _bar: string;

    public getBar: () => string;
    public setBar: (value: string) => this;
}
```

As it's written in the [mixins docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#understanding-the-sample):

> To satisfy this requirement, we create stand-in properties and their
>   types for the members that will come from our mixins. This satisfies
>   the compiler that these members will be available at runtime.

I used `getBar` and `setBar` because you can't reuse the name of the method, unless you'll do:

```
class Foo {
    @GenerateGetterAndSetter() _bar: string;

    public get bar(): string {
        return null;
    }

    public set bar(value: string) {}
}
```

In this case you'll have to have dummy implementations which you can then override with the decorator.
But with a setter you can not return anything, if you try you'll get:

> A 'set' accessor cannot have a return type annotation

---

#### Edit

Based on your comment that your implementation has one method, you won't be able to use "stand-in properties" because it won't allow for two different signatures:

```
class Foo {
    @GenerateGetterAndSetter() _bar: string;

    public bar: () => string;
    public bar: (value: string) => this; // error: Duplicate identifier 'bar'
}
```

What you can do is use a factory function:

```
class Foo {
    @GenerateGetterAndSetter() _bar: string;
}

type FooImplementation = {
    bar(): string;
    bar(value: string): Foo;
}

function createFoo(): Foo & FooImplementation {
    return new Foo() as Foo & FooImplementation;
}
```

But you won't be able to return `this`, only `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks fo clairfying it was impossible. Hoping to see `declare` inside a class in a future release as I don't see how it can be harmful, but looks like very few people are doing this sort of thing.

Comment: I wouldn't wait for `declare` to be allowed out of ambient context as it has a very specific porpuse (see this post: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/). In your case I would just divide the implementation into two different functions (it will probably create a more readable code also) and then use the mixins trick